# creating pdf file with python using pdfkit

Tags: python

I am trying to use pdfkit module on python to create pdf file from text. the first time I ran the following code, it was alright, but after the second attempt the background of the created file is dark, I tried to write this code into a different file and execute it but the result is the same.
Would somebody please show me how to fix it.
Thanks.

This is the code I tried to test the pdfkit:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3 
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_string('MicroPyramid', 'micro_2.pdf')
```

Comment: this code works correctly on Linux Mint 19.2, Python 3.7, pdfkit 0.6.1

Comment: did you run it in console/terminal to see if you don't get error message? Did you delete `micro_2.pdf` before running code again ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a different library, try [pdfme](https://github.com/aFelipeSP/pdfme). It's the most powerful library in python to create PDF documents.

```
from pdfme import buid_pdf

with open('micro_2.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    build_pdf({'sections': [{'content': ['MicroPyramid']}]})
```

Check the docs [here](https://pdfme.readthedocs.io/)